# TypeScript call method in method = TypeError: this.print is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've got a main.ts file:

```
import { App } from './app';
import './styles.scss';

ready(new App().init);

function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState !== 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
```

and an app.ts file:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {

    }
    private print = (str: string) => console.log(str);
    init(){
        this.print('test');
    }
}
```

When I run this with the ts-loader in webpack using this tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es2015.iterable"]
    }
}
```

I receive the error: Uncaught TypeError: this.print is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.App.init (app.ts:17)

I've tried creating the method as private print(str){ console.log(str); }
but this didn't solve it.

How can I get the method call in the init() method to work?

EDIT: forgot to add, I'm running webpack v. 1.14.0 and TypeScript 2.1.5 (tried with 2.1.4 also)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `new App().init` without binding it, and when it is executed the `this` isn't what you think it is.

You should do this:

```
let app = new App();
ready(app.init.bind(app));
```

Another option:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    }

    private print = (str: string) => console.log(str);

    init() {
        this.print('test');
    }
}
```

Or you can use an arrow function:

```
export class App {
    constructor() {}

    private print = (str: string) => console.log(str);

    init = () => {
        this.print('test');
    }
}
```

The thing with arrow functions though is that it won't put the method on the prototype of the class, but instead will add it as a property of the instance.
That is fine in most cases, but if you're planning on subclassing the `App` class and override the `init` method then you'll have a problem calling `super.init`

Comment: this is entirely correct. Another option is to pass `() => app.init()`

Comment: Thanks, I've indeed forgot to make the init method an arrow function also. I can confirm that the other options work too. Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to write

```
import { App } from './app';
const app = new App();
ready(() => app.init());
```

This doesn't affect inheritance or prototypes or in any way change the behavior of class `App`.

That said, Nitzan Tomers's answer contains valuable information that is highly important to learn and understand.